# Move div off screen containing draggables after drop and keep dragged elements positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using JQuery drag and drop.  I want to move the div containing the draggable elements ('elements') off screen, and keep the draggable elements positioned on their corresponding slots after being dropped.

Now when all the draggables are in their slots, I move the div containing the slots to the left by adding a class and then set the position of the draggables to match the slots:

```
$("#slots").addClass('left');
$( "#element1" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_1"});
$( "#element2" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_2"});
etc
```

Once this is done, I then present a video above the dragged elements, and also above the div 'elements'.  The problem is that the div 'elements' is still taking up space...so I want to move it off screen.  I have tried doing this with absolute positioning, but then the dragged elements don't get set to their slots, they appear over the video directly above the slots.

I also tried changing the class 'left' which gets added to the div 'slots' to:

```
#slots.left {
position:absolute;
top:400px;
left:30px;
}
```

But this results in the dragged elements not being positioned on the slots despite using:

```
$("#slots").addClass('left');
$( "#element1" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_1"});
$( "#element2" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_2"});
etc
```

Basically I just want to lessen the vertical space between the video and the dragged elements by doing something with the elements div taking up that space...

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4pBWT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to hide the parent div that contain your dragged elements before showing your video:

```
$('#elements').hide();
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pBWT/1/)

---

You can try to adjust the `margin-top` of your `#drag_drop` div:

```
$('#drag_drop').css('margin-top', '-70px');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pBWT/2/)**

Comment: Tried that..as you can see in your fiddle, that also hides the dragged elements.

Comment: Yep, that works...also tested changing the 'left' class to this and does the same:#slots.left {
position:relative;
top:-70px;
left:-190px;
}